# Data is transcribed in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

*Info:* When you add new rows in DataGridView with previous removed and overwrite the default content.
[image: DataGridView]

*How it work:* When i click to button, i select some data in new form.

```
 Private Sub ButtonOk_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButtonOk.Click
    FormNoveZaznamy.DataGridViewUrazy.Rows(0).Cells(7).Value = "Test"
    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

That's work. But when i check RedBox, it add new row and **in all other rows** *set default data*. (Rewrite)

*Info:* I do not know how to solve it, anywhere in the code, the code that would not have crossed all the lines and set the default data.

Comment: And the question is? BTW, you source code can be useful.

Comment: @duDE , I adjusted it to the desired format. And question is, how it made to don't overwrite rows.

Comment: FormNoveZaznamy.DataGridViewUrazy.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(7).Value = "Test"  will re-write JUST the current row ! but put all your code .. because I don't understand your english ..

Comment: @CristiC777, Yes I know, it's supposed to work, but when I got to the last line'll add something, *! * This creates a new row and everywhere the content changes *! * (This function and there never have). But the mouse that I was onto something, that's what I test if it will FUNCTIONAL, write the answer here.